# Not able to run command (Teiid)

Tags: jboss, jboss-eap-7, teiid

Not able to run this command after started server in Teiid Designer.

```
<jboss-install>/bin/jboss-cli.sh --file=bin/scripts/teiid-standalone-mode-install.cli
```

Is there any other methods to add Teiid.
I am also not getting the Teiid instance in designer.

I am using Teiid Designer 10.4
Teiid 9.2
Jboss EAP 7

Answer (score 1):

You do not have to run that command. Where you configured the server, configure such that you are using "standalone-teiid.xml" instead of "standalone.xml".

Alternatively, you can start the Teiid Server outside of Designer at command line by executing

```
<wildfly>/bin/standalone.sh -c standalone-teiid.xml
```

then in Designer, you need to configure such that you connecting to a remote server. Here the Designer will not invoke another process but connect to Server that is already running externally to Designer.